# Convert uint8_t* data_chars and length into String equivalent

Tags: c++, string, arduino

I have these 2 variables `uint8_t* data_chars` and `unsigned int length`.

`data_chars` is a pointer to an array of characters. `length` is the number of characters.

I would like to convert it to the String object used in Arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, because there is no constructor for the buffer and its size, you have to do it yourself:

```
String data;
data.reserve(length+1); // prepare space for the buffer and extra termination character '\0'
for (int i = 0; i<length; ++i) {
    data += (char)data_chars[i]; // typecast because String takes uint8_t as something else than char
}
```

However it's kinda wasting a memory.

BTW: if you've used `char * data_chars` it'll be working even without type casting.

Comment: Sorry that I switched answer. The answer provided by wk_sg is the correct one after some testing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by KIIV is almost correct. However, I believe the 100% correct answer would be below;

```
String data;
data.reserve(length+1); // prepare space for the buffer and extra termination character '\0'
for (int i = 0; i<length; ++i) {
    data += (char) data_chars[i];
}
```

You need to cast `data_chars[]` to char to be completely sure. Tiny modification from KIIV's answer. The credit still goes to KIIV.

Comment: In theory, you can edit my answer. There is no need for adding another answer that differs in only one typecast.

Comment: KIIV, you are correct and I cannot undo what I have done. I will request the OP to mark your answer as the correct one. Sorry about it.

Comment: wk_sg, Ok. If you don't mind, I will do just that. KIIV deserves it more.